# $\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int{\frac{1}{(z^{2}-a^{2})^{1/2}}dz}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you please integrate $$\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int{\frac{1}{(z^{2}-a^{2})^{1/2}}dz}$$
over a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin enclosing the points $z=+a$ and $-a$ where $a>0$ (Principal value of square root is taken) by taking the residue at infinity and also in the second method by
defining the contour around the branch points and along the branch cuts between $z=-a$ to $z=a$, to find that the integral is $$\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^a{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}dx}.$$

Comment: Trig substitution might help.